# Как вернуть значение переменной для новой переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, dict

Есть код, который транслирует ввод пользователя в латиницу.
Функция описана выше кода, это не так интересно.

---

**Код:**

```
nom = str(input('Фамилия:'))
prenom = str(input('Имя:'))
n = latinizator(nom, legend)
p = latinizator(prenom, legend)
n = n.capitalize()
p = p.capitalize()
index = p + n
print(index)
```

**Вывод:**

Фамилия: Иванов

Имя: Иван

IvanIvanov

---

Как сделать IvanIvanov **именем словаря автоматически**, чтобы пользователь вводил имя, фамилию и генерировался словарь **IvanIvanov** = {}, чтобы потом его можно было заполнить ключами со значениями, которые предполагается ввести дальше.

Answer (score 2):

создай словарь и храни в нем

```
users = {}
nom = str(input('Фамилия:'))
prenom = str(input('Имя:'))
n = latinizator(nom, legend)
p = latinizator(prenom, legend)
n = n.capitalize()
p = p.capitalize()
index = p + n
users[index] = {}
print(index)

# теперь по index можешь заполнять словарь
users[index]['age'] = int(input("Введите возраст числом"))
print(users)
```

по просьбам трудящихся. все переменные храняться в словарях locals() и globals(). манипулируя ими можно динамически создавать переменные в пространстве имен

```
index = str(input('index:'))
globals()[index] = {}
print(globals())
print(wow)
```

в данном случае если ввести не wow то получим NameError. и вообще лично мое мнение идея обречена на провал.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в моём коде появилась именно эта переменная с таким именем. Мне нужно, чтобы создавался словарь IvanIvanov = {} . Если такое возможно, конечно же.

Comment: Возможно, но как ты будешь этим пользоваться? Представь себе что тебе нужно описать алгоритм работы с объектом, которого еще нет и ты даже не представляешь какое у него будет имя) попытайся объяснить мне зачем тебе именно переменная с таким именем и чем тебя не устраивает словарь?

Comment: Нужно было создать свою библиотеку книг и авторов. Я это сделал, но захотелось модернизировать так, чтобы можно было вводить данные автора и названия книги, и имя автора становилось переменной, как в вопросе. Дальше на основе неё создаётся словарь с описанием автора: имя, фамилия, отчество, годы жизни и название любимой книги (всё на русском). И эти все переменные скоплены в одном словаре, через который можно вести поиск по ключам и будет выдаваться вся информация об авторе.